# Ape files (Monkey's Audio): How to create them under Trusty and Xenial?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, convert, batch

I have seen plenty of useful information on Ask Ubuntu about how to *play* Monkey's Audio or APE files. However I would like *create* these files from a collection of wav files using either command line or GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way under Trusty Tahr or Xenial Xerus is to use the Monkey's Audio Console Front End of Matthew T. Ashland. mc3man holds a package in his PPAs for either Trusty or Xenial. Add the required PPA and install this application as follows:

**1. Installation for Trusty Tahr**

Use the following commands from a Terminal window to add this PPA and install the monkeys-audio package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/trusty-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monkeys-audio
```

**2.Installation for Xenial Xerus**

Use the following commands from a Terminal window to add this PPA and install the monkeys-audio package:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/xerus-media
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install monkeys-audio
```

**3. Usage**

Installation instructions are fairly basic and can be seen by running `mac -h`. For a single file the following would work well:

```
andrew@ilium~$ mac luckynight.wav luckynight.ape -c4000
--- Monkey's Audio Console Front End (v 4.11) (c) Matthew T. Ashland ---
Compressing (extra high)...
Progress: 100.0% (0.0 seconds remaining, 1.2 seconds total)          
Success...
andrew@ilium~$
```

And for a collection of wav files the following loop would also work quite nicely:

```
mkdir ape && \
for j in *.wav
do 
mac "$j" ape/"${j%.wav}.ape" -c4000
done
```

And now enjoy your Monkey's Audio music :).

**References:**

- [PPA: Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media)
- [PPA: Ubuntu Multimedia for Xerus](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/xerus-media)